# How do I access an object through another object?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, code.org

I am trying to create a chess game as a beginner, one of the problems I encountered is that I need a piece holder to hold the values that are assigned to a piece. The piece holder will change the location of each piece but I need to change the value of the original piece

I've tried adding another holder object but that would lead to the same problem. Then, I've tried just leaving the dots and seeing if it would work which the program could not recognize. Then, I put parenthesis around it in hopes that it would be changed and then register but it did not work either.

```
function pieces(piece ,posX, posY, moveCount, tileLocation, turn) {
  this.piece = piece;
  this.posX = posX;
  this.posY = posY;
  this.moveCount = moveCount;
  this.tileLocation = tileLocation;
  this.turn = turn;
}
function pieceHolder(pieceHold, extra, turn, color, tile){
  this.pieceHold = pieceHold;
  this.extra = extra;
  this.turn = turn;
  this.color = color;
  this.tile = tile;
}
onEvent("wpawn1", "click", function() { //"wpawn1" is the id for another button
  holder.pieceHold = wpawn1.piece;
  holder.extra = 5;
  holder.turn = wpawn1.turn;
  holder.tile = wpawn1.tileLocation;
});


var holder = new pieceHolder();
var wpawn1 = new pieces("wpawn1", -5, 285, 0, "a2", 0, "w");
var wpawn2 = new pieces("wpawn2", 35, 285, 0, "b2", 0, "w");

holder.piece.tileLocation = holder.tile; // did not work
(holder.piece).tileLocation = holder.tile; // did not work
```

I was hoping that holder.piece would be converted to the name such as wpawn1 or wpawn2. Then it would register it as wpawn1.tileLocation or wpawn2.tileLocation. Neither of them would work and the program could not understand my code.

Comment: When you say `holder.piece` do you mean `holder.pieceHold`? You haven't defined a `piece` property on `pieceHoder`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var holder = new pieceHolder({});
```

When constructing the holder object you don't pass anything as piece, so it's `undefined`. When trying to access `holder.piece.tileLocation` you are trying tileLocation from `undefined`.
The better way would be to always use default for you parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is fine but you are trying to reach the content of `holder` object before callback (function) in `onEvent` parameter gets executed.